# what is the equivalent of np.fill_diagonal in dask

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I have a correlation matrix, where I fill the diagonals with 1 using np.fill_diagonal and then take the upper triangle using np.triu.
but for the correlation matrix I am using dataframe.corr which gives memory error for number of columns above 5000.
Hence I am creating a dask dataframe and then using corr to calculate the correlation matrix.

However, I am not being able to replicate fill_diagonal and np.triu in diagonal.
Can someone please help me with this?

Below is the snapshot of sample data and expected output. I have also put the python code currently in use to achieve the expected output. My objective is to do these operations in dask to avoid memory error for large dataframe ( 5 million records and 5800+ columns) and calculate the results.
This code is part of a larger function to remove multi-collinear variables from data and is being replicated in dask.

```
input

h_id    cu_id   tax     rev_m1      io_m1
0       0       0       0           0
0       0       0       1           0
0       0       1       0           -1
-1      1       0       0           1
1       0       0       0           -1
0       0       0       0           0
0       0       0       0           -1
1       0       0       -1          0
-1      1       0       0           0
0       0       0       0           -1

python code to acheive the desired output:

column_names = data.columns
#Create covariance matrix
correlation_matrix = data.corr()

print('*'*10 + "\nDone creating correlation matrix of standardized X.")
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
#Save the Covariance Matrix to a CSV
df_correlation_matrix = pd.DataFrame(correlation_matrix, columns = column_names, index = column_names)

np.fill_diagonal(df_correlation_matrix.values, 1)

# Writing values from upper triangle of the correlation matrix to new data frame
df1 = df_correlation_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(df_correlation_matrix.shape)).astype(bool)).stack().reset_index()

df1.columns = ['Variable1','Variable2','Value']
df1.drop(df1[df1.Variable1 == df1.Variable2].index, inplace=True)


Expected output:
Variable1   Variable2   Value
h_id        cu_id       -0.79
h_id        tax         0.0
h_id        rev_m1      -0.35
h_id        io_m1       -0.49
cu_id       tax         -0.16
cu_id       rev_m1      0.0
cu_id       io_m1       0.62
tax         rev_m1      0.0
tax         io_m1       -0.36
rev_m1      io_m1       0.0
```

Comment: `fill_diagonal` could be constructed with the current array API and `map_blocks(.., block_info=None)`, but you want this with a dataframe?

Comment: correlation matrix is a square matrix. Can da.diag work? (http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.diag)

Comment: If you want to fill upper triangular with lower triangular when one of them is all zero: `arr + arr.T`.

Comment: wait. we don't know what do the input and output look like. Can you give us an example that we can run in python with some fake data?

Comment: Hello @Rzu.. I have updated the question with input and expected output. Kindly check!